# How to fix file has been attached or not on client side

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I am struggling on a File upload button, where in it works properly when I implement it independently.
But when I copy the same code in my main form it does not work.

```
i.e. $_FILES['file']['name']
```

does not give me any output.
infact I get

```
Notice: Undefined index: error message.
```

I tried to check if `isset($_FILES[file]` works. this says that file has not been set.

From this I think I can say that at client side itself my file is not been fetched.

**FORM.PHP**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-push-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Photograph: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="stud_photo" id="stud_photo" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-push-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="register"  id="register" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" value="Submit"> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

**conn.php**

```
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
            # code...

        $student_name = $_POST['surname'] . " " . $_POST['middlename'] . " " . $_POST['firstname'];
        $student_name = str_replace("'", "''", $student_name);
        $department_id = $_POST['department_id'];

        $university_reg_no = $_POST['university_reg_no'];

        $address = str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['address']);
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
        $distance = $_POST['distance'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $Blood_group = $_POST['Blood_group'];


        $stud_photo = $_FILES['stud_photo']['name'];
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($stud_photo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $stud_photo = $university_reg_no.".".$imageFileType;
}
```

Note: I am using PHP with ORACLE. But I don't think so this is affecting that.

Comment: Where is your form code??

Comment: Where is your `form tag` ??

Comment: @Saty: `<form role="form" name="register" action="a.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

Comment: your action is `a.php` and you show us code of `conn.php`

Comment: Yes. its the same file.

Answer (score 0):

**for Files need to add this attribute into your form tag.**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['stud_photo']))
        {
          if(empty($_FILES['stud_photo']['type'][0]))
          {
            //your code here for file not found
          }
          else
          {
            //your code here for file found
          }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried out this but it says file has not been set.

Comment: I tried ur code. It doesn't  go inside any loop. Not even in  `if(isset($_FILES['file'])){`

Comment: `if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
                        if(empty($_FILES['stud_photo']['type'][0]))
                        {
    //your code here for file not found
                         echo "File not found";
    }
else
{
/// Your code here for file found
 echo "File  found but donno";
}
    }

    else{
     echo "File not attached";
    }`


I get File not attached

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" add this attribute into your form tag. and after try this code.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine when i run only the file upload button. but same when i try with other inputs the gives me error. where as all other input tags are posted to my connection page.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code. here i am test all things work perfectly with all input element adding.**

```
  <title>file upload sample</title>


  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
            # code...

        $student_name = $_POST['surname'] . " " . $_POST['middlename'] . " " . $_POST['firstname'];
        $student_name = str_replace("'", "''", $student_name);
        $department_id = $_POST['department_id'];

        $university_reg_no = $_POST['university_reg_no'];

        $address = str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['address']);
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
        $distance = $_POST['distance'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $Blood_group = $_POST['Blood_group'];


        $stud_photo = $_FILES['stud_photo']['name'];
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($stud_photo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $stud_photo = $university_reg_no.".".$imageFileType;
}

  ?>

  <!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script> -->





</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-push-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Surname: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Middle name: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">First name: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Department Id: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="text" name="department_id" id="department_id" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Univercity reg no: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="text" name="university_reg_no" id="university_reg_no" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Address: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <textarea name="address"></textarea>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">State: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="state" id="state" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">City: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Zip: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Email: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Distance: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Phone: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Blood Group: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                   <input type="text" name="Blood_group" id="Blood_group" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Photograph: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="stud_photo" id="stud_photo" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-push-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="register"  id="register" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" value="Submit"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
</body>

</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Surname: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Middle name: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">First name: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Department Id: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <input type="text" name="department_id" id="department_id" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Univercity reg no: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <input type="text" name="university_reg_no" id="university_reg_no" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Address: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <textarea name="address"></textarea>
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">State: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="state" id="state" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">City: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Zip: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Email: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Distance: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Phone: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Blood Group: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                       <input type="text" name="Blood_group" id="Blood_group" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Upload Photograph: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <input type="file" name="stud_photo" id="stud_photo" />
                                    </span>
                                </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-push-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="register"  id="register" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" value="Submit"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
                # code...

            $student_name = $_POST['surname'] . " " . $_POST['middlename'] . " " . $_POST['firstname'];
            $student_name = str_replace("'", "''", $student_name);
            $department_id = $_POST['department_id'];

            $university_reg_no = $_POST['university_reg_no'];

            $address = str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['address']);
            $state = $_POST['state'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $zip = $_POST['zip'];
            $distance = $_POST['distance'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $Blood_group = $_POST['Blood_group'];


            $stud_photo = $_FILES['stud_photo']['name'];
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($stud_photo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $stud_photo = $university_reg_no.".".$imageFileType;
    }

      ?>
```